# How do I create a good database with SQL Server for a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to develop a form with asp.net Webform and would like to display in a ListBox or checkbox data from SQL Server. So I can call the elements of the table, there is no problem. But the worry is that I'd like to stored information that the user has selected / chosen the  form in a different table because in the future I would like someone developer can not change the elements of the form without touching the code but just touch Sql server management Studio.

I hope you understand my problem ... Do you have a solution?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand. The traditional way to do this is with two tables, one for responses and one for options

Comment: You mean a table with the different data to display the elements of the form and a table to put the data of the user ?

Comment: The best way to *store* data is rarely the same way as the best way to *present* or *collect* data from users.

Comment: I've attempted an answer - can you read this and retitle your question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a master table where all your master data resides. Ex. list of languages to be shown in `Checkbox` or `Listbox`.

And there will be another table which holds the user inputs usually referencing the Ids of master data along with other user inputs.

Ex.

```
Languages -> master table
-----------------------------
LanguageID
Name

UserDetails -> detail or actual table where you can store your user's inputs as well as the LanguageId from language table
-----------------------------
UserId
Name
City
LanguageID -> foreign key which reference of Language table
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what you're after.

Typically the way to do this is to have two tables in your database.

```
Options
 - OptionID
 - OptionName
// maybe an isactive flag?


Responses
 - ResponseID
 - OptionID
// maybe a username?
```

Your form then shows all the active options on the page. When a user comes along you create a response row where the OptionID is set to the ID of the option the user chose (with an appropriate foreign key).

Your developer can then add and deactivate options without removing users' responses.